# Why recursive function doesn't inherit a variable value from the main function in js?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```js
let adder = () => {
  if (sum === undefined) {
    var sum = 0
  }
  sum = sum + 10
  console.log(sum)
  if (sum >= 100) {
    return sum
  }
  adder()
}
```

Please explain why the sum = 0 every time the recursive function is being activated? Why doesn't it accumulate?

Comment: `var sum` gets hoisted to the top of the function, so your function is effectively `var sum; if( sum === undefined) sum = 0;` which is *always true*.

Comment: Pass the value you want to accumulate to the next call of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in javascript are always scoped inside the function they're called from. If you define a `sum` variable inside a function and call a function, **even if it's the same function**, that function will not have access to the variable. You can, however, define a global variable, and the inner function will have access to it. However, this is not recommended and goes against the concept of recursion.

Solution 1 (global variable, not recommended):

```js
// note how this is declared outside of any function
var sum;
let adder = () => {
  if (sum === undefined) {
    // the var here is gone to avoid redeclaring at a local scope
    sum = 0
  }
  sum = sum + 10
  console.log(sum)
  if (sum >= 100) {
    return sum
  }
  // we also return the value
  return adder()
}
```

Solution 2 (proper recursion, recommended):

```js
// note how sum is an argument now
let adder = sum => {
  if (sum === undefined) {
    sum = 0
  }
  sum = sum + 10
  console.log(sum)
  if (sum >= 100) {
    return sum
  }
  // we pass sum in as an argument and return it
  return adder(sum)
}
```

Comment: @Aplet123, Thank you! I get the idea. Could you also explain why undefined is being returned when sum reaches 100 in case I use a recursive function adder(sum) without return in a solution 2.

Comment: The last `adder` call returns 100, but that's not being returned by the previous `adder` calls, so it just defaults to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

How about utilising the closure property?

```js
const adder = (sum = 0) =>
  () => ++sum

const a = adder()
const b = adder()

console.log(a(), a(), a()) // 1 2 3
console.log(b(), b(), b()) // 1 2 3
console.log(a(), a(), a()) // 4 5 6
console.log(b(), b(), b()) // 4 5 6
```

Or give the adder a parameter -

```js
const adder = (sum = 0) =>
  (n = 1) => sum += n

const a = adder()
const b = adder()

console.log(a(10), a(10), a(10)) // 10 20 30
console.log(b(), b(), b()) // 1 2 3
console.log(a(), a(), a()) // 31 32 33
console.log(b(), b(), b()) // 4 5 6
```